# Comma after first author name in authoryear biblatex style with two authors

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I am using the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,%
natbib=true,      % enable natbib macros
%firstinits=true, % use initials as first names
dashed=false,     % do not use a dash instead of author name in case of several publications
useprefix=true,
maxnames=100,     % in the bibliography show all names
maxcitenames=2,   % in the text use et al. for more than 2
backref=true,     % have backrefs in the bibliography
]{biblatex}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1mm}
\setlength\bibhang{1cm}

%print authors in smallcaps everywhere
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{%
  \ifmknamesc{\textsc{#1}}{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifmknamesc} and test {\ifuseprefix} }
    {\textsc{#1}}
    {#1}}

\def\ifmknamesc{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcurrentname{labelname}}
               or test {\ifcurrentname{author}}
               or ( test {\ifnameundef{author}} and test {\ifcurrentname{editor}} ) }}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{gillies,
  author = {Gillies, Alexander and Mister Miller},
  title = {Herder and the Preparation of Goethe's Idea of World Literature},
  journaltitle = {Publications of the English Goethe Society},
  volume = {9},
  date = {1933},
  pages = {46--67}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citep{gillies}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

However this gives:
`GILLIES, Alexander and Mister MILLER (1933). “Herder and the Preparation
of Goethe’s Idea of World Literature.” In: Publications of the English
Goethe Society 9, pp. 46–67 (cit. on p. 1).`

But I want:

`GILLIES, Alexander, and Mister MILLER (1933). “Herder and the Preparation
of Goethe’s Idea of World Literature.” In: Publications of the English
Goethe Society 9, pp. 46–67 (cit. on p. 1).`

How can i add the comma?

Comment: So far, you have asked five questions and have accepted answers for three of them. However, you didn't cast any vote until now. Please consider to upvote useful questions and answers, especially answers to your questions. Note that upvoting an answer has to be done separately from accepting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to your preamble either:

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
%  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}% DELETED
  \finalandcomma% ADDED
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
```

or in case you don't want the additional comma in citations:

```
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
%    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}% DELETED
    \finalandcomma% ADDED
    \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}%
}
```

Output for the second variant:

[image]