# Add comma between author and year with et al

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I am using `biblatex` with `style=authoryear` and `maxcitenames=2`. For a reference with more than two authors \cite command produces

> Erkus et al. 2010

and \textcite command produces

> Erkus et al. (2010)

I would like to add a comma between `et al.` and the year only for the `\cite` command (but not for the `\textcite` command), i.e.,

> Erkus et al., 2010
>
> Erkus et al. (2010)

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

Works only for single author references ( [see this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134063/how-to-add-a-comma-between-author-and-year)), but does not work with the shorthand use of `et al.` for references with more than two authors. I do not want to use `\DefineBibliographyStrings` to redefine `andothers` and add comma after `et al.` since it also adds comma to `\textcite` citation, which I don't want.

I tried the following ([see this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359296/biblatex-comma-after-first-author-with-two-authors)) but did not work:

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{%
     \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{2}{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}%
}
```

Comment: @moewe: Thanks very much for the responses. If the renew command is expected to work, maybe some other adjustment I did creates and issue. I have customized the bibliography and citation format a lot, so there is a possibility that I messed up smtg. I will look into this and post here the results.

Comment: @Alex: natbib changes many of my customized bibliography settings. So maybe I should not use it.

Comment: Since Alex and I haven't commented under this post we won't receive notifications for comments you write here, even if you use `@<usrername>`. Comment directly under our answers instead. That way you can make sure that we are pinged.

Comment: Indeed I suspect that something else is going on at your end. Since `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}` should work (as I write in my answer, `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}` would be preferred, but both work in essentially the same way). I guess the best thing would be to come up with an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that shows your current bibliography/citation setup. (Incompatibilities like this are the reason why we always like MWEs very much even if the question is simple.)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the `natbib=true` option in the `\usepackage` for `biblatex`.

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
@inproceedings{erkus_2010,
  title = {Title},
  booktitle = {Book Title},
  date = {2010},
  author = {Erkus, Firstname and Lastname, Firstname and Lastname Anotherfirstname}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, backend=biber, natbib=true] {biblatex}

\addbibresource{database.bib}

\begin{document}

Cite: \cite{erkus_2010}

Textcite: \textcite{erkus_2010}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Cite with comma between 'et al.' and year, and textcite without said comma.]

Answer (score 0):

`\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}`should work for regardless of whether you cite one or more authors. In recent versions of `biblatex` `nameyeardelim` is a context-sensitive delimiter, which means you should use `\DeclareDelimFormat` to modify it

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,aksin,herrmann,nussbaum}

\textcite{sigfridsson,aksin,herrmann,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998; Aksın et al., 2006; Herrmann et al., 2006; Nussbaum, 1978//Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998), Aksın et al. (2006), Herrmann et al. (2006) and Nussbaum (1978)]

If you take a look at [`blx-natbib.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-natbib.def#L4), you'll see that it uses exactly the same command as suggested here. That's why `natbib=true` (as suggested in [Alex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/181064/alex)' [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502595/35864)) also produces the desired comma.